# openCV - How to rebuild from .zip files downloaded for github for python in windows 8.1?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I was trying to run a face recognition code that I got from [here](https://openlab.ncl.ac.uk/gitlab/john.shearer/clappertracker/blob/335f53c74ba7dc1e75a69126628e952212b77365/src/3rdparty/opencv/samples/python2/facerec_demo.py). I was getting the following error:

```
model = cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createEigenFaceRecognizer'
```

So, I googled for the error and they suggested to get the face recognition file from [Github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib). I downloaded the entire file as zip and I dont know how to rebuild to my openCV for python. I installed openCV for python using the 'whl' file that I downloaded from 'Unofficial windows binaries for python.' Could anyone please tell how to rebuild from the downloaded zip files, and the exact to location to where I should rebuild? Am I supposed to copy and paste the c++ header (found inside the face module) anywhere to my computer?

Comment: if you don't like to compile opencv3 (+ the opencv_contrib) repo from src, you have to fall back to opencv2.4, where above still works

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the answer is simpler than that! You only need to change two lines. Right now, you probably have:

```
import cv2
```

Change it to:

```
from cv2 import FaceRecognizer
```

---

#### Key concept: *modules*

`cv2` is a **module**, a large collection of a bunch of different classes. Look around their website to see some of the other classes they provide. `FaceRecognizer` is a class *inside* `cv2`, and *that* is the class you are looking for.

---

So, with that in mind, change:

```
model = cv2.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
```

to:

```
model = FaceRecognizer.createEigenFaceRecognizer()
```

and you should be good as gold. Happy trails.